# Debugging SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure-changing SQL Service Account

Tags: sql-server

In order to debug a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure, I would like to change the account that the SQL Server (MSSQLSrver) service is running under, namely, changing the account from "Network Service" to my current user account.

However, if something goes wrong, I would like to be able to change it back and I am concerned that since this is a built in account for which I never knew the password, that I will not be able to set it back w/o knowing what the password is.

Will this be an issue?

Comment: that would almost certainly be the wrong way to go about it...

Answer (score 0):

"Network Service" user does not need a password. You just need to be computer administrator to set the service to run under "Network Service" account.